# Hbase cluster space issue

Tags: hbase

I want to free up disk space in cluster.So i deleted all versions of data that are 2 weeks old. Even after deleting the cluster space has not increased. Can anyone tell me the reason?
Is it because the length of my store file index is large
or hbase has not run major compaction?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you deleted your data, but, here are a couple of thoughts.

1)  Yes, if a major compaction has not run, then, there will be not decrease in your store files.
2)  If you deleted your data manually, that is, with the "Delete" action, make sure that the action you used was either : 
  deleteColumns or deleteFamily or the constructor new Delete( row, timsetamp )

anything else will only delete the version at the specified timestamp and not all versions equal to and smaller than the specified timestamp.

API : https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Delete.html

Hope that helps some?  Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you inserted rows with a timestamp and set the table TTL value correctly (which must be a unix timestamp) and run a major compaction then table size must decrease if there exists any row with appropreate timestamp.